# containing and accessing thread globals in c++

Tags: c++, oop, metaprogramming

A design problem which I've seen in several workplaces I've been to, yet without a satisfactory solution:

Suppose you have a system with dynamic number of threads.

Each thread must have an access to a set of "singletons", the singletons have one and only one instance per thread (therefore they are not real singletons, but singletons per thread)

This set of singletons is known at compile time.

Each of the singletons has a default constructor (in order to simplify things, nevertheless, a solution that does not have this constrain would be great)

A satisfactory solution should have the followings:

1. Each thread can access any of its singletons in o(1) time
2. An access to a singleton is lock free
3. Adding a singleton to the 'singleton set' does not require new code written on the set side
4. The 'singleton set' is populated during compile time

I'm not sure if such a design is feasible. If it is, I assume that it requires a little bit of meta programming.

Thanks in advance for any of your insights.

Comment: This is impossibly vague and underspecified--not even clear what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread-local variables nicely solve the problem.

```
// in .h
class ThreadSingleton
{
private:
    static __thread ThreadSingleton* thread_specific_instance;

public:
    static ThreadSingleton* get() { return thread_specific_instance; }
    ThreadSingleton();
    ~ThreadSingleton();
};

// in .cc
__thread ThreadSingleton* ThreadSingleton::thread_specific_instance;

ThreadSingleton::ThreadSingleton() {
    if(thread_specific_instance)
        std::abort(); // one instance per thread please
    thread_specific_instance = this;
}

ThreadSingleton::~ThreadSingleton() {
    thread_specific_instance = 0;
}

// usage
int main() {
    // on thread entry
    ThreadSingleton x;

    // later anywhere in the thread
    ThreadSingleton* px = ThreadSingleton::get();
}
```

Each thread creates `ThreadSingleton` somewhere on the stack, normally in the thread function. Later on `ThreadSingleton` is accessible from anywhere in that thread via `ThreadSingleton::get()` which returns the singleton of the calling thread. (The above can be made a template to wrap any other class, I didn't do it for simplicity of exposition).

Performance-wise accessing thread-local variables doesn't require any calls (unlike using thread-specific storage created using [`pthread_key_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pthread_key_create.html)) See http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf for more details.

Comment: Unless you're stuck with a pre-2011 compiler, it's probably better to use the standard `thread_local` keyword rather than a compiler-specific extension like `__thread`.

Comment: You're right, it would be better. But even best 2012 compilers don't support it. http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you're describing thread-local storage.

In C++11, you just need to declare a variable `thread_local` to get a separate instance for each thread.

In C++03, the most portable solution is [`boost::thread_specific_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html); alternatively, your compiler and/or system library might provide thread-specific storage, such as POSIX's `pthread_key_create` and friends.

Comment: I would recommend using pre-standard `__thread` storage declarator ([most compilers have supported it for quite a while](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#Language-specific_implementation)) for performance-sensitive code. `boost::thread_specific_ptr` although being a portable solution requires a library call to access the stored pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, usually I'd post this in the comments, since I'm not quite sure if I even understood your question correctly...but isn't it sufficient to create instances of your singleton set in the constructor of the parent Thread class?

Assuming you have three classes A, B and C (known at compile time)
And one 'Thread' class.

Wouldn't you declare instances of A, B, and C in your thread header

```
class Thread {
private:
    A *a;
    B *b;
    C *c;
public:
    Thread();
}
```

and then instantiate them in the constructor of your thread?

```
Thread:Thread() {
    a = new A();
    b = new B();
    c = new C();
}
```

This way, each thread 'owns' the singletons exclusively, which means it can access them at any time, without having to worry about race conditions or locks.

Regarding 'adding a singleton', may I suggest creating a 'Singleton-Parent' class and then use a standard container (like std::list) on which you can push the new pointer to?
Of course, access to this list would have to be protected by a lock, when you're doing it during runtime, under compile time, this won't be necessary.
During compile time, you may be best off to use a static array of pointers, which will allow you to access the pointers as fast as possible.

Again, sorry if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: thanks, the solution you have proposed is the best solution I came with yet. My problem with it is that whenever I want to add a new class I must compile Thread and anyone who is using it. I wish 'Thread' would have been a service or a library that could have been reused.

Comment: @Ezra No, actually not. You see, when adding a new class to Thread, you recompile Thread...and done. All those who 'use' thread, aren't affected, as long as you don't change the header of 'Thread' you're good. (Which would mean that you'd have to go with a std:list instead of a static array, OR simply place a pointer *Singleton in your header file and then create the array dynamically in the Thread constructor with 'new Singleton[x]';
Please do not forget to free the classes you instantiate this way though.

Comment: Its too intrusive and rigid. `Thread` has to have access to constructors of `A`, `B` and `C`. Also, creating those may require constructor arguments that may be unavailable until later on.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I understand that it's a bit...shall we say 'old fashioned', but you HAVE to tell it what subclass of a parent class you want it to have at some point.

(Stupid enter key submit, sorry)
*Ahem*, the only other solution that comes to mind, is to have one class, where all the classes are declared and included and a function, which adds it to a list...but essentially that's the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your question properly, but for me the "set" of singletons is irrelevant. You have a fixed number of singletons, call them `Singleton1` to `SingletonX`, where `X` is known at compile time. It doesn't really matter for the threads.

For the actual singletons, you could have them inherit from a single templated base class that handles the per-thread part. Something like this:

```
template<class B>
struct SingletonBase
{
    static B &getInstance()
        {
            // One instance per thread
            static std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, B> intances;

            if (instances.find(std::this_thread::get_id()) == instances.end())
                instances[std::this_thread::get_id()] = B{};

            return instances[std::this_thread::get_id()];
        }
};

class Singleton1 : public SingletonBase<Singleton1>
{
    // ...
};
```

If you don't want separate distinct classes for the singletons, you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to store them:

```
class Singleton : public SingletonBase<Singleton>
{
    // ...
};

std::array<Singleton, X> singletons;
```

This will create an array of the specified number `X` at compile time, and can be accessed like a normal array: `Singleton &instance = singletons[0].getInstance();`.

Note that my example code uses features from the "new" C++11 standard library.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I didn't intend for this to be complete, just show a simple example.